# Python: Output a numbered variable every time a function is called?

Tags: python

I'm using turtle to show a sorter. I have the number sorting working fine but I am working on sorting the bars. I would like to know if there's a way to assign the output of a function to a variable each time it is called. More specifically, I want to be able to assign each separate bar to a variable, and then put all the bar variables into a list and sort it simultaneously with the numbers from nums. Hopefully I'm making sense. Any help would be appreciated.

```
nums=[30,60,90] ##sorted list

draw(): ##draws the bar based on height of number in the list
    t.fd(5)
    t.lt(90)
    t.fd(nums[i])
    t.lt(90)
    t.fd(5)
    t.lt(90)
    t.fd(nums[i])
    t.lt(90)
    t.pu()
    t.fd(50)
    t.pd()

for i in range(len(nums)): ##draws all lines in the list
    draw()
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this:

```
def draw(num): ##draws the bar based on height of number in the list
    t.fd(5)
    t.lt(90)
    t.fd(num)
    t.lt(90)
    t.fd(5)
    t.lt(90)
    t.fd(num)
    t.lt(90)
    t.pu     # typo?
    t.fd(50)
    t.pd()

nums=[30,60,90] ##sorted list

for num in nums:
    draw(num)
```

If not, please give an example of what you're trying to achieve.